# How do I find an object in image/video knowing its real physical dimension?

Tags: c++, matlab, image-processing

I have a sample of images and would like to detect the object among others in the image/video already knowing in advance the real physical dimensions of that object. I have one of the image sample (its airplane door) and would like to find the window in the airplane door knowing its physical dimensions(let we say it has inner radius of 20cm and out radius of 23cm) and its real world position in the door (for example its minimal distance to the door frame is 15cm) .Also I can know prior my camera resolution.  Any matlab code or OpenCV C++ that can do that automatically with image processing?
Here is my image sample
[image: door sample]

And more complex image with round logos. 
[image: complex image]

I run the code for second complex image and do not get the same results. Here is the image result.
[image: Results of complex image]

Comment: It sounds pretty advanced. First, you would need to know all the parameters of airplaine- with, height, how round the corners are and so on. Then from which angle the photo/video was taken. Depending on these parameters you would detect plane's front, top and bottom coordinates inside image/video and create, for example, rectangle, which would serve as measurment/map. When that's done, you could search objects within airplane and measure them.

Comment: You need use in function that you can find in browser (you need match them to your image). there are many function for it. I don't did in this theme but I know that you can find in easy many function that do it and you need match them to your image (nobody will do that for you :) ).

Comment: First of all, you need calibrate for the radial distortion of the camera in all your image. Otherwise, the dimensions will be distorted and indeed different across images.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a circle in the image so i suggest you use Hough circle transform.

1. Convert image to gray
2. Find edges in the image
3. Use Hugh circle transform to find circles in the image.
4. For each candidate circle sample the values of the circle and if the values corresponds to a predefined values accept.

The code:

```
clear all

% Parameters
minValueWindow = 90;
maxValueWindow = 110;

% Read file
I = imread('image1.jpg');
Igray = rgb2gray(I);
[row,col] = size(Igray);

% Edge detection
Iedge = edge(Igray,'canny',[0 0.3]);

% Hough circle transform
rad = 40:80; % The approximate radius in pixels
detectedCircle = {};
detectedCircleIndex = 1;
for radIndex=1:1:length(rad)
    [y0detect,x0detect,Accumulator] = houghcircle(Iedge,rad(1,radIndex),rad(1,radIndex)*pi/2);

    if ~isempty(y0detect)
        circles = struct;
        circles.X = x0detect;
        circles.Y = y0detect;
        circles.Rad = rad(1,radIndex);
        detectedCircle{detectedCircleIndex} = circles;
        detectedCircleIndex = detectedCircleIndex + 1;
    end
end

% For each detection run a color filter
ang=0:0.01:2*pi; 
finalCircles = {};
finalCircleIndex = 1;

for i=1:1:detectedCircleIndex-1

    rad = detectedCircle{i}.Rad;
    xp = rad*cos(ang);
    yp = rad*sin(ang);

    for detectedPointIndex=1:1:length(detectedCircle{i}.X)

        % Take each detected center and sample the gray image
        samplePointsX = round(detectedCircle{i}.X(detectedPointIndex) + xp);
        samplePointsY = round(detectedCircle{i}.Y(detectedPointIndex) + yp);

        sampleValueInd = sub2ind([row,col],samplePointsY,samplePointsX);
        sampleValueMean = mean(Igray(sampleValueInd));

        % Check if the circle color is good
        if(sampleValueMean > minValueWindow && sampleValueMean < maxValueWindow)
            circle = struct();
            circle.X = detectedCircle{i}.X(detectedPointIndex);
            circle.Y = detectedCircle{i}.Y(detectedPointIndex);
            circle.Rad = rad;
            finalCircles{finalCircleIndex} = circle;
            finalCircleIndex = finalCircleIndex + 1;
        end
    end
end

% Find Main circle by merging close hyptosis together
for finaCircleInd=1:1:length(finalCircles)
    circleCenter(finaCircleInd,1) = finalCircles{finaCircleInd}.X;
    circleCenter(finaCircleInd,2) = finalCircles{finaCircleInd}.Y;
    circleCenter(finaCircleInd,3) = finalCircles{finaCircleInd}.Rad;
end
[ind,C] = kmeans(circleCenter,2);
c = [length(find(ind==1));length(find(ind==2))];
[~,maxInd] = max(c);
xCircle = median(circleCenter(ind==maxInd,1));
yCircle = median(circleCenter(ind==maxInd,2));
radCircle = median(circleCenter(ind==maxInd,3));
% Plot circle
imshow(Igray);
hold on

ang=0:0.01:2*pi;
xp=radCircle*cos(ang);
yp=radCircle*sin(ang);
plot(xCircle+xp,yCircle+yp,'Color','red', 'LineWidth',5);
```

The resulted image:
[image]

Remarks:

- For other images will still have to fine tune several parameters like the radius that you search for the color and Hough circle threshold and canny edge thresholds.
- In the function i searched for circle with radius from 40 pixels to 80. In here you can use your prior information about the real world radius of the window and the resolution of the camera. If you know approximately the distance the camera was from the airplane and the resolution of the camera and also the window radius in cm you can use this to get the radius in pixels and use this for the hough circle transform.

[image]

Comment: Ok thanks. The challenging here that can be another circle as you mentioned (like company logos or any other painting) . So What kind of filtering and techniques can use to find exactly the window I need. Any sample code for that purpose filtering?

Comment: You can use the color of the window and the circle. Maybe identify also another prominent feature like the door or the arrow on the door and according to the relative position between the circles that you found and the other feature filter out the wrong circles. If you will add another more complex image i will try to write a code that will filter wrong circles.

Comment: yes sure. Will. Btw the code for this simple circle is not in C++? Any chance to write that code for more complex image to filter  wrong circles to be in C++?

Comment: Actually my goal is to find the door frame. So I can you the physical dimensions of some  prominent features like window or door handle and their relative position to the door frame or their distance to the door frame to identify the door. yes sure I will add another more complex image. Btw the code for this simple circle is not in C++? Any chance to write that code for more complex image to filter  wrong circles to be in C++?

Comment: The code itself is in Matlab. I can't write it in c++ but i think you understand the code so it isn't supposed to be to difficult to convert it to c++

Comment: Ok. Added more complex image with two circle/round logos. Please can you write the code that will filter the wrong circles?

Comment: I tried to run the Matlab code but can not . I have the image Processing toolbox installed as with command ver I can see it. Matlab error is  Error in circle (line 11)
    [y0detect,x0detect,Accumulator] = houghcircle(Iedge,rad(1,radIndex),rad(1,radIndex)*pi);  Any help?

Comment: Sorry. I found the error. Actually I need the function houghcircle. Now work. But when tried your code on the second more complex image it  could not find the window

Comment: I forgot to give the link to hough circle :https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9833-hough-transform-for-circle-detection.

Comment: Yes. I found it. But the code does not work on complex image. It could not find the window on the second more complex image. Any help? Or can you give me the code can work on complex images and filter out the window?

Comment: I will look at it and will get back to you

Comment: I tried the new code for the complex image and do not get the same result as you @Amitay Nachmani. I posted my result. What is the problem?

Comment: when you run the second code what is the value you get for the variable rad?

Comment: I got 58 for variable rad.

Comment: I just copy paste the code and run it. Did not change anything.

Comment: What is the size of the image you read? the variable I in the code?

Comment: Size of the image. Dimensions 1632x868 pixels. Horizontal resolution 96dpi, Vertical resolution 96dpi. Bit depth 24. The variable I in the code is 868x1632x3 uint8

Comment: i have no idea what is the difference. I will look at it.

Comment: I fixed a bug in my code try now hopes it works this time.

Comment: Thanks. Its works now. One question.What if the logos are same dimension as the window (same radius,  same area.. maybe same grey color). The code is going to filter them out and detect the window only or?

Comment: No it will detect them also you should really understand the code and  make it more robust.

Comment: I see... But how then to filter only the window if there are logos same dimension and color?

Comment: You can do the following: Use the distribution of colors inside the circle. Or use the gradient distribution in the circle or the best option do some machine learning and train a classifier that detect the window. Good luck

Comment: Machine learning is not so good at the moment as I dont know how the logos can be paint. I think color distribution or gradient distribution is ok. Any sample code how to do that? Also the relative position between the circle (window) and the door (or the door arrow on the door) is good. Please any help code on this?

Comment: I tried to use the color distribution inside the circle. But I do not know how to filter the window circle. Because houghcircle function does not have any color related argument. So how to do it? Any small help on this?