# How to find the relative position between two objects in the image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, distance

I would like to find the relative position between the circle (red one in the image) and the door (or the door arrow on the door). I was able to detect the window (red circle on the image) and now would like to know the relative position between the circle and the door(door arrow) and also the minimal distance between the circle and door(door arrow). The minimal distance to to vertical door arrow and the minimal distance to the horizontal door arrow.

I posted the code to find the window(red circle) and two images( original one and the result image of finding the window). Any code or function that gives me that relative position and distances?

Here the code to find the window (MatLab) from  Amitay Nachmani from this post

> [How do I find an object in image/video knowing its real physical dimension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38654958/how-do-i-find-an-object-in-image-video-knowing-its-real-physical-dimension/38678669?noredirect=1#comment64809767_38678669)

```
clear all

% Parameters
minValueWindow = 90;
maxValueWindow = 110;

% Read file
I = imread('image1.jpg');
Igray = rgb2gray(I);
[row,col] = size(Igray);

% Edge detection
Iedge = edge(Igray,'canny',[0 0.3]);

% Hough circle transform
rad = 40:80; % The approximate radius in pixels
detectedCircle = {};
detectedCircleIndex = 1;
for radIndex=1:1:length(rad)
    [y0detect,x0detect,Accumulator] = houghcircle(Iedge,rad(1,radIndex),rad(1,radIndex)*pi/2);

    if ~isempty(y0detect)
        circles = struct;
        circles.X = x0detect;
        circles.Y = y0detect;
        circles.Rad = rad(1,radIndex);
        detectedCircle{detectedCircleIndex} = circles;
        detectedCircleIndex = detectedCircleIndex + 1;
    end
end

% For each detection run a color filter
ang=0:0.01:2*pi; 
finalCircles = {};
finalCircleIndex = 1;

for i=1:1:detectedCircleIndex-1

    rad = detectedCircle{i}.Rad;
    xp = rad*cos(ang);
    yp = rad*sin(ang);

    for detectedPointIndex=1:1:length(detectedCircle{i}.X)

        % Take each detected center and sample the gray image
        samplePointsX = round(detectedCircle{i}.X(detectedPointIndex) + xp);
        samplePointsY = round(detectedCircle{i}.Y(detectedPointIndex) + yp);

        sampleValueInd = sub2ind([row,col],samplePointsY,samplePointsX);
        sampleValueMean = mean(Igray(sampleValueInd));

        % Check if the circle color is good
        if(sampleValueMean > minValueWindow && sampleValueMean < maxValueWindow)
            circle = struct();
            circle.X = detectedCircle{i}.X(detectedPointIndex);
            circle.Y = detectedCircle{i}.Y(detectedPointIndex);
            circle.Rad = rad;
            finalCircles{finalCircleIndex} = circle;
            finalCircleIndex = finalCircleIndex + 1;
        end
    end
end

% Find Main circle by merging close hyptosis together
for finaCircleInd=1:1:length(finalCircles)
    circleCenter(finaCircleInd,1) = finalCircles{finaCircleInd}.X;
    circleCenter(finaCircleInd,2) = finalCircles{finaCircleInd}.Y;
    circleCenter(finaCircleInd,3) = finalCircles{finaCircleInd}.Rad;
end
[ind,C] = kmeans(circleCenter,2);
c = [length(find(ind==1));length(find(ind==2))];
[~,maxInd] = max(c);
xCircle = median(circleCenter(ind==maxInd,1));
yCircle = median(circleCenter(ind==maxInd,2));
radCircle = median(circleCenter(ind==maxInd,3));
% Plot circle
imshow(Igray);
hold on

ang=0:0.01:2*pi;
xp=radCircle*cos(ang);
yp=radCircle*sin(ang);
plot(xCircle+xp,yCircle+yp,'Color','red', 'LineWidth',5);
```

And two image
[image: original one]

[image: Rec circle]

Comment: If you're using someone else' code, it is good to give that person some credit as all this code clearly appears to be an answer from one of your previous posts! http://stackoverflow.com/a/38678669/5698672

Comment: ok. Sorry I did know how to do that, I will do the credits now. .Edit the post

Comment: Don't you want to try for yourself first ?

Comment: I will but I do not know any algorithm about relative object position . Any hint or advice from where to start?

Comment: Did the questions on the other post got solved? If so, accept the answer that helped you. Else, do not duplicate your questions

Comment: I done it.. Accepted the answer. Its not a duplicate question. Its a new one

Comment: Just curiours. Arent you useing the code from the non-accepted answer?

Comment: I accepted the answer, The code is to find the window and it works. Only need bit tuning to filter like some logos with same color and dimension as the window. Now I wonna know the relative position of the window and its minimal distance to to door line(horizontal and vertical one).